# Regex in mongoDB Compass. Filter all data that not contain some characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to filter in a DDBB in mongoDB Compass all the results that have in "name" any character that is not a letter or a number.

It can be the character alone or with others characters that are valid.

What am I doing wrong?

`{ name: {"$regex": "^(?!0-9a-zA-ZÄÖÜäöüß )"} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've undestood correctly you can use this regex: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "[^a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüß]"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sMbh9lEky8C)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing also a space after the ß and the search was giving me strings with spaces between words. I fix it just adding it: ```({"name": {"$regex": "[^a-zA-Z0-9ÄÖÜäöüß ]"}})```